# Como otimizar minha paginação (DataTable) usando LIMIT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tudo bem? venho tendo alguns probleminhas há um tempo, com uma tabela minha do meu sistema, a minha tabela possui apenas **430** registros, e sempre que eu dou *"F5"*, realizo um `INSERT` ou algo do tipo, a tabela "buga/demora" e volta, e isso vem me incomodando.

> Eu tentei utilzar `Server-Side` já, que é uma "propriedade" da DataTable, porém, achei um pouco 
>   complicado...

Estava vendo alguns tópicos e sites, do pessoal usando a função `LIMIT` em suas paginações, para um melhor desempenho, porém, **não entendi como eu irei fazer para usar a função `LIMIT` em cada página da minha DataTable**...

**Exemplo:** (Essa é a minha consulta mySQL)

```
$sql = "SELECT contas.* , estabelecimento_detalhes.* FROM contas, estabelecimento_detalhes WHERE contas.estabelecimento = estabelecimento_detalhes.estabelecimento AND contas.categoria != 'EMPRESA-X' LIMIT 1,10";
```

**Nessa minha consulta, só exibe 10 registros da minha tabela.**

Como eu posso fazer para consultar somente 10 em 10 registros?

*Vou estar disponibilizando todo o código da minha paginação abaixo:*

```
<!-- LISTAGEM  -->  
       <div class="main-content">
              <h3><center><i><a style="font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;"><b>CONTAS PAGAS </b></a></i></center></h3>
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">



      <table class="table-earning full_table_list" id="dtHorizontalExample" cellspacing="0" width="100%">


        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="th-sm">Estabelecimento</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Categoria</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Mês referênte</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Parcela/Valor total</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Valor pago</th>               

                <th class="th-sm">Banco</th>                

                <th class="th-sm">Tipo do Pg</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Pago</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Vencimento</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Nota fiscal</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Nº Documento</th>

                <th class="th-sm">OBS</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Anexo</th>

                <th class="th-sm">Opções</th>

                <th class="th-sm" style="visibility: hidden;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
  <tbody>


<?php
$sql="";
require('conexaobd.php');


if (isset($_GET["pesquisa"])) {
$estabelecimento = $_GET["pesquisa"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contas WHERE estabelecimento LIKE '%$estabelecimento%'";
}else

$sql = "SELECT contas.* , estabelecimento_detalhes.* FROM contas, estabelecimento_detalhes WHERE contas.estabelecimento = estabelecimento_detalhes.estabelecimento AND contas.categoria != 'EMPRESA R&C'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$inc = 0;

while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    $valor_dividido = $cont['valor'] / 100;

// No primeiro ECHO, estou exibindo o nome com o link do visualizar.
    echo '
    <tr>

    <td><a href="#" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" title="Ver info" style="color:black">
    '.$cont['estabelecimento'].'</a></td>'; 

    echo "             
    <td style='color:black'>".$cont['categoria']."</td>
    <td style='color:black'>".$cont['mes']."</td>
    <td style='color:black'>".$cont['parcela']."</td>
    <td style='color:black'> R$ ".number_format($valor_dividido, 2, ',', '.')."</td>
    <td style='color:black'>".$cont['banco']."</td>
    <td style='color:black'>".$cont['tipo_pg']."</td>
    <td style='color:black'>".converte_data($cont['pagamento'])."</td> 
    <td style='color:black'>".converte_data($cont['vencimento'])."</td> 
    <td style='color:black'>".$cont['nota_fiscal']."</td>
    <td style='color:black'>".$cont['n_documento']."</td>
    <td style='color:black'>".$cont['obs']."</td>";

// Exibindo comprovante com icone
echo $cont['comprovante'] != "" ? "<td><a href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads_pagamentos/{$cont['comprovante']}' title='{$cont['comprovante']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/comprovante.png' style='width:30px; height:30px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";

    echo "     
    <td> 
    <div class='table-data-feature'>

    <a href='edit_contas.php?ID_contas=".$cont['ID_contas']."' target='new_blank' title='Editar' style='color:black'>
    <i class='zmdi zmdi-edit' style='margin: 0 8px'></i>
    </a>

    <a href='del_contas.php?ID_contas=".$cont['ID_contas']."&categoria=".$cont['categoria']."&pagamento=".$cont['pagamento']."' target='new_blank' title='Excluir' confirm='Tem certeza que deseja deletar essa conta?' style='color:black'>
    <i class='zmdi zmdi-delete' style='margin: 0 8px'></i></a>

    </div>
    </td>


    <td style='display: none;'>".json_encode($cont)."</td>

    </tr>";

          } ?>  

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sou novo em programação, aceito qualquer tipo de ajuda/dica, agradeço.

Comment: já tentou usar offset? assim `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`

Comment: Ainda continua sendo exibido 10 registros, por que está `LIMIT 10`... eu quero que a cada página ele consulte outros 10 registros...

Answer (score -1):

O que o @Ricardo Pontual comentou faz sentido e é a forma correta. Você precisa atualizar seu OFFSET, não o limite.

OFFSET é um deslocamento que começa em 0.

Exemplo:

```
-- se desloca da primeira linha pelas próximas 10
select
    *
from minha_tabela
limit 10 offset 0 

-- se desloca da 11ª linha pelas próximas 10
select
    *
from minha_tabela
limit 10 offset 10
```

Para mostrar de 10 em 10 no seu HTML, só precisa de uma aritmética simples: cada vez que alguém clicar num número da paginação, por exemplo, você consulta no banco de dados, multiplicando OFFSET 10 por esse número menos 1.

O link com o número 1 (página 1), por exemplo, enviaria OFFSET {10 * (1 - 1)};
O link com o número 2 (página 2), enviaria OFFSET {10 * (2 - 1)};

Claro que você poderia colocar a contagem das páginas a partir de 0 no HREF do link também, aí seria só multiplicar esse número pelo OFFSET.

O OFFSET também pode ser alterado. Sabe aqueles `dropdown` que informam quantos registros por vez você quer exibir? Bem, é o OFFSET. 10, 25, 50, 100 registros por página.